# Spring security websockets

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

I have problem trying to add authentication on websockets using spring security.
At this point I have configured http to work with the current security configuration and it works fine - I am able to authenticate users and it returns authenticated principal. However I want to add some websocket security and as soon as I put the following class the app logs me but it does not want to open any websockets:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends
        AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    protected void configureInbound(
            MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
        messages.nullDestMatcher().permitAll().simpDestMatchers("/app/**")
                .authenticated()
                .simpSubscribeDestMatchers("/user/*", "/topic/*")
                .authenticated();

        // TODO
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The WebSocketSecurityConfig is correctly initialized because when I add permitAll() instead of authenticated() it allows me to open websocket.
I am sure that if the http principal is authenticated the websocket principal is also authenticated. I used this as a reference:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/websocket.html

Here is the error in the console:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Failed to send message to ExecutorSubscribableChannel[clientInboundChannel]; nested exception is org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:127)
at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.StompSubProtocolHandler.handleMessageFromClient(StompSubProtocolHandler.java:266)
at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.handleMessage(SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.java:309)
at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.WebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(WebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:75)
at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:56)
at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:72)
at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.handleTextMessage(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:112)
at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.access$000(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:42)
at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter$3.onMessage(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:82)
at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter$3.onMessage(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:79)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.sendMessageText(WsFrameBase.java:393)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processDataText(WsFrameBase.java:494)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processData(WsFrameBase.java:289)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processInputBuffer(WsFrameBase.java:130)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.onDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:56)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler$WsReadListener.onDataAvailable(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:203)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletInputStream.onDataAvailable(AbstractServletInputStream.java:203)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractProcessor.upgradeDispatch(AbstractProcessor.java:92)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:609)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:232)
    at org.springframework.security.messaging.access.intercept.ChannelSecurityInterceptor.preSend(ChannelSecurityInterceptor.java:71)
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel$ChannelInterceptorChain.applyPreSend(AbstractMessageChannel.java:158)
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:113)
    ... 24 more
```

My configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@EnableScheduling
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Autowired
HandshakeHandler handshakeManager;

@Autowired
AbstractManagerEventListener eventListenerHandler;

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Override
public void configureWebSocketTransport(
        WebSocketTransportRegistration registration) {
    registration.setMessageSizeLimit(512 * 1024);
    registration.setSendBufferSizeLimit(1024 * 1024);
    registration.setSendTimeLimit(40000);
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/channelSocket").setHandshakeHandler(
            handshakeManager);
}

@Bean
public HandshakeHandler handshakeManager() throws Exception {
    return new HandshakeManager();
}
```

}

And my HandshakeHandler class:

```
public class HandshakeManager extends DefaultHandshakeHandler {

    @Override
    protected Principal determineUser(ServerHttpRequest request,
            WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Map<String, Object> attributes) {

        Principal principal = request.getPrincipal();
        return new UserPrincipal(principal.getName());
    }
}
```

The `determineUser(ServerHttpRequest request,
                WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Map<String, Object> attributes)`

returns the same principal as the principal of the user who is authenticated.
Any help is appreciated!Thank you!